# iOS UIKit Dynamics - unable to add bouncy behaviour for a view

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uikit, uikit-dynamics

I am trying to add a bouncy behaviour (collision detection) to view which contains all the contents like buttons and images named as `ViewContent` [it should fall from top and collide/bounce with the bottom of screen].

Here is my **view Hierarchy**:

[image: view Hierarchy]

and Code:

`viewController.h`

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollisionBehaviorDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewContent;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *animator;

@end
```

*in storyboard I've set the `viewContent` frame as (0, -568, 320, 568) so that is should come from top*

`viewController.m`

```
@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewContent]];
    gravityBehavior.gravityDirection = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0);

    [self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];

    UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewContent]];

    collisionBehavior.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;
    collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self;
    [self.animator addBehavior:collisionBehavior];

    UIDynamicItemBehavior *contentViewBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[viewContent]];
    contentViewBehavior.elasticity = 0.4;

    [self.animator addBehavior:contentViewBehavior];
```

**As a result nothing happens**. I'm following this tutorial http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uikit-dynamics/ and able to add a collision detection on a square with frame `(100, 100, 100, 100)`, but not able to add collision on a view having frame `(0, 0, 320, 568)`.

I'm new and can't figure it out, any ideas/suggestion please.

**Update**
*Nib view added as @Fogmeister suggested.*
I've added a separate nib view file named as `LoginView` and assigned the `LoginViewController` class so that I am able to add IBOutlets and IBActions from this Nib.

In `LoginViewController's` ViewDidLoad method just added these lines right under the `[super viewDidLoad`

```
self.content = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                 loadNibNamed:@"ViewLogin"
                 owner:self options:nil]
                firstObject];

[self.view addSubview:self.content];
```

rest of the code is remain same except in `initWithItems` `viewContent` is just replaced with this newly created view `self.content`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't use `AutoLayout` and `UIKit Dynamics` together. They just don't work together at all.

Also, the first rule of AutoLayout is that you can't update the frame of a view directly. So your line `self.viewContent.frame = CGRectMake = (0, -568, 320, 568);` won't work either.

What you need to do with this view is disable AutoLayout in order to use Dynamics.

Seeing as you are using a storyboard then the problem is that disabling auto layout for one view will disable it for all views.

If you just want the main view to bounce then what you can do is define that view in a separate nib (or in code).

Either way you then need to programmatically add that view to the view controller's view.

Then your dynamics will work.

Comment: thanks for great suggestion. Removing autolayout is not an option so I'll go for separate nib option.

Comment: I've created a separate nib file and assigned same class to this nib i.e. LoginViewController and in ViewDidLoad method I added these line:

self.content = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
      loadNibNamed:@"ViewLogin"
      owner:self options:nil]
     firstObject];
 
 [self.view addSubview:self.content];

and nothing happens :(

Comment: Question is edited, Please take a look and let me know, Thanks.